# Insert in Database is executed only the first time I start the ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

My issue is that in my ASP.NET application,the insert in a database with data from a form is executed only the first time when the application starts. After that, the insert is nor being done.

I tried to debug the application and in debug mode the data is inserted every time. I also used SQL Server profiler and there is no insert in the database being made except the first time I'm submitting the form in the database. But when I run in debug mode, the insert is done without any problems.

This is the method from Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(Product p)
{
    IO.Insert(p);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is the method that does the insert:

```
public static void Insert(Product pr)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]))
    {
        connection.Open();

        string s = "INSERT INTO Product (Id, Name, Price, Description, Category, Image) VALUES (@GUID, @Name, @Price, @Description, @Category, @Image)";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = pr.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pr.Price;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pr.Description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pr.Description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = IO.ImageInsert(pr.Picture);

            cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not using any other threads other than main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having the command within the using block, `cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();` initiates the asynchronous execution of the Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure that is described by this SqlCommand. You aren't waiting for it to complete either by polling to determine whether the command has completed, using the `IsCompleted` property of the `IAsyncResult` returned by the BeginExecuteNonQuery method or using the `AsyncWaitHandle` property of the returned `IAsyncResult`.

You can change your code as follows to wait for the command to execute.

```
IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
   // Wait till the command executes
   Console.WriteLine("Waiting for query execution");
}
Console.WriteLine("Command complete. Affected {0} rows.", cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result));
```

Per Microsoft

> The BeginExecuteNonQuery method starts the process of asynchronously
>   executing a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure that does not
>   return rows, so that other tasks can run concurrently while the
>   statement is executing. When the statement has completed, developers
>   must call the EndExecuteNonQuery method to finish the operation. The
>   BeginExecuteNonQuery method returns immediately, but until the code
>   executes the corresponding EndExecuteNonQuery method call, it must not
>   execute any other calls that start a synchronous or asynchronous
>   execution against the same SqlCommand object. Calling the
>   EndExecuteNonQuery before the command's execution is completed causes
>   the SqlCommand object to block until the execution is finished.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but just to add, I think for this case it is easier to just use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 1):

you can use ExecuteNonQuery instead of BeginExecuteNonQuery because you'r closing the connection and query is still running.

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` for single insert or you can use thread pool

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("blahblah;Asynchronous Processing=true;") {
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("someProcedureName", sqlConnection)) {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}});
```